# Disable automatic rebooting after a bugcheck

Tags: windows, debugging, bsod

I want to absolutely disable the auto-reboot after any kind of crash in Windows.
So, I set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\AutoReboot
```

to 0, which is supposed to disable auto reboot.

However, the next time the computer bugchecked, it automatically rebooted.  Why?

Comment: I mentioned that it's rebooted by bugcheck.

Comment: Yes.and I have already figured out the reason. Need reboot for the registry. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing any of the settings in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl
```

you must reboot the machine before the change will take effect.